# how to change the link of document when archived in SharePoint 2013

Tags: following, archive

Scenario: I am following a document, that shows on home page as " domain name\ is now following test.docx document "(url-https://libraries-shp. itn. intranet /abc /test.docx) . when i archive that document, the url changed to  https://archive-shp.itn.intranet/abc/test.docx. After archiving when i click on followed document it shows page can not be found and the link shows old url.

Requirement- either the followed document url should be changed to archive one or the document should be removed from followed document list after archiving.

Please suggest how i can do this.

Thanks,

Alok

Comment: I faced a similar issue, but I took a different approach to it.  This might not work for your requirements, but you could create a Yes/No field called Archive.  Then select 'Yes' to archive a document.  You then would need to update any views where you only want to display active documents - filter on the Archive field to only show documents where Archive=No or blank.